# More than one selector in Jquery if statement

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 2 statements like this:

```
if ($('#lcheckbox').prop('checked')) {
        ajaxData.mktgoptin=$form.find("[name='optin']").val();
}
```

and

```
if($("input[type='hidden'][name='optin']").length) {
       ajaxData.mktgoptin=$form.find("[name='optin']").val();
}
```

Since what happens in the if condition is the same, I am wondering it there is way combine them into one. I tried Or operator, multiple selector trick but no avail. Any tips?

Comment: Please show how you used the "*Or operator, multiple selector trick*," and explain how it failed to work (what did it do wrong, what did it not do at all).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Or operator "||" to combine the two conditions :

```
if ( $('#lcheckbox').prop('checked') || $("input[type='hidden'][name='optin']").length) {
// your code
}
```

That's work on the exemple https://jsfiddle.net/jg92g5oe/